# Draw line over image with PyQt

Tags: python, drawing, pyqt4, mouseevent

I want to make a python script where I show an image and then the end user can draw an arrow over this image by clicking two points.

I would like the line to be an arrow, and to show it following the pointer of the mouse until the user click for the second time.

Working with Python3, PyQt4, Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use paintEvent and QPainter:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 500, 300)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("myPic.png")
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
        pen = QPen(Qt.red, 3)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, self.rect().width() -10 , 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! it works for me, got to tinker about getting mouse coordinates over the image. Just one last thing... How can I draw line with an arrow shape at one end?? since my goal is to draw arrow :)

Comment: i'd suggest to just draw a triangle at the end of the line @f126ck

Comment: Thanks!!! Ok, understood.. but just one thing. I'm writing a bigger program where the user is prompted to draw theirselves the line/arrow. User click the starting point, and then the end point of the "vector" line. I want to provide a mechanism alongside the user is drawing to give them feedback about the actual working of the program.  I thought of countinously draw the line following the mouse pointer coordinates, and to permanently draw it over the image when they click the second time.  (To understand what I want to achieve, think about MS Paint while you draw a line...)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Velcro. I appreciate much of it. You're being a friend. Basically I want the user to click over a point coordinate in the image, and then PROGRAMMATICALLY start to draw a line connecting this first point clicked, and the mouse pointer, so that the program shows interactively the path of this line. At the end, and only at the end, when user clicks for the second time a point, I want to show and draw permanently this line (connecting this two dots) over the image. Thanks again.